# Непохожие "Похожие"

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, похожие-вопросы

С каждым разом, релевантность вопросов в колонке "Похожие" всё меньше. Специально прошёл по всем предложенным вопросам - никакой связи с вопросом на скриншоте, кроме метки [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

<sup>Да простят меня участники за размер скриншота.</sup>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторюсь, раньше работало довольно неплохо, но ситуация ухудшается последние год-два. Причём на enSO такого не наблюдается.

Что-то сломали, так задумано, или я просто не понимаю логики выдачи?

Comment: Так это же просто робот по каким-то словам набирает...

Comment: @Qwertiy: вот и хочется разобраться - по каким словам? Совпадений то нет. И почему раньше это работало более-менее сносно?

Comment: По мне так "Похожие"  всегда плохо работали. Вероятно, word2vec модель более слабая для русского языка.

Comment: вот отличная похожесть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377538/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C Тоже вопрос без текста из одного кода.

Comment: @Эникейщик: согласен - всё, что на английском, то подтянулось. А из русского - пара совпадений по сумме всех заголовков :) Кстати, гляньте на Похожие прямо здесь, в текущем вопросе - тут, на Мете, работает? 0_о

Comment: Думаю, что это потому что метка похожие-вопросы более конкретная, чем яваскрипт. Там подтянулось, что под руку попалось, а здесь все по теме.

Comment: А нельзя ли отключить этого робота?